# How to embed a Media Player

Tags: c#, .net, media

How to embed a Jukebox or a media player in C# .NET?

Or rather create a playlist which can play WAV files.

Comment: Do you want to embed a media player-like control in a windows application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed microsoft media player COM component and control it from code.

[How to interact with Windows Media Player in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478/how-to-interact-with-windows-media-player-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Soundplayer to just play sound, windows media player for audio/video playback on a form

[Soundplayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx)
[Windows media player](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/satisharveti/EnhancedWindowsMediaPlayer07072008021113AM/EnhancedWindowsMediaPlayer.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET Framework 3.5 and WPF, you can try System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.aspx