# How to interface with Windows Media Player in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-media-player

I need to synchronize Windows Media Player with my application.  I want to show the current song that WMP is playing in a ListBox in real time, with updates when WMP changes songs.  How can I implement this?

Comment: Binary, we collided. I rolled back since I essentially scrubbed his question and started over.

Comment: Sorry Gortok ,,from 2 days im not sleeping ,maybe for you it is simple but i don0t know how work out this trouble as it is last one feature to complete my project.
I don't wish give you bother .
Have a happy day.
;)

Comment: @JayJay: The problem isn't your question, it was that it's not written in legible english. We just edited it to make sense of the question.

Comment: Thanks Gortok...
<next time i will be more careful ;)

Comment: JayJay: Do you want this community to write your entire application? *points at previous questions*

Comment: @Honsa. Ii don't know who are you but sure you are not the creator of this community as you are not the creator of the role of this community,if i wish post 5 questions in one day i can .Only a person like you have bad thoughts about people no one asked your help.Don't offend people.
Have a HappyDay

Comment: Ok, I don't want to start a flaming here, but your questions are usually answered by two minutes spent on Google. But you're right, it's not my place to tell you what you can and cannot ask here. I am entitled to an opinion, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of sniffing around in Google gave me this: [http://brandon.fuller.name/archives/hacks/nowplaying/wmp/](http://brandon.fuller.name/archives/hacks/nowplaying/wmp/#overview), it looks like you need to write a plugin for WMP that exposes the information to your application. Depending on what you need/cost, the Plugin on that page might do the job!

Answer (score 0):

Poll HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\Player\RecentFileList\File perhaps.

Comment: Hi Stuart,
i store the songs from a folder and this folder will be update each week.
Thanks for you reply

Answer (score 0):

We've controlled Windows Media Player through the Windows Media library (wmp.dll) and .NET Remoting, using a singleton service.

Comment: Hi Aaron do you use ListBox in your project to show the current playlist ?
Have a fun.

Answer (score 0):

Look here: 
[How to interact with Windows Media Player in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478/how-to-interact-with-windows-media-player-in-c/764856#764856)