# How can I control an instance of Windows Media Player in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, process, wmp

I'm trying to control windows media player in c#. That means, I want to be able to programmically play songs. To reiterate, I'm talking about the full version of WMP, not the component you can embed into a windows form. I can launch the WMP process just fine, the problem comes in actually controlling it as I can't think of any keypresses I can send to the player that would tell it to select a song and play music. I can do this in iTunes just fine by sending a spacebar key-press to the process, but not so in Windows Media Player. Does anyone have any ideas as per how I can control widows media player programmically in C#? Is there a special command I can send to the process to complete this task?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to interact with Windows Media Player in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478/how-to-interact-with-windows-media-player-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a link do how to interact with WMP using p/invoke](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/wmp_pinvoke.aspx)...

[This is a question that's almost identical to this one that has already been answered in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478/how-to-interact-with-windows-media-player-in-c).