# Enqueuing songs in windows mediaplayer

Tags: c#, windows-media-player

Anyone successfully managed to queue a song to the current playlist in windows mediaplayer  (running instance) (Windows 7/Vista).

I've researched everything from different commandline arguments, different process.start verbs  to what the enqueue context menu uses in regedit but nothing seems to work...

If anyone can figure this one It'd be deeply appreciated :)

Comment: My initial googling seems to indicate you're not going to have much fun whatever you do. This question might get you on the right track though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478/how-to-interact-with-windows-media-player-in-c