# Getting windows media player currently playing song

Tags: c#, windows, windows-media-player

Is there a way I can get currently plaaying song from Windows Media Player by C# with .NET? Any API that will work with all Windows Media Player versions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478/how-to-interact-with-windows-media-player-in-c

Comment: sorry I have already read this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what HPT suggested should work. But if you want to access it using C#, please refer to

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562405%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: perfect, can you guide me towards a point where I can read to create WMP plugins using C# as well?