# Metro JS API - Get current media player track?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'd like to query Windows Media player from an external app to find out what track (album and artist) it's currently playing.

Is that information exposed anywhere? I've looked into the [Windows.Media-Namespace](http://Windows.Media-Namespace) but couldn't find a way to receive this information or track changed events and such.

Comment: Is your plan that the external app is a Windows 8 metro application or do you plan to have it be a standard desktop application?

Comment: I'd like to develop a metro app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar questions regarding 'How to read currently playing track in WMP' may be appropriate, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681576/getting-windows-media-player-currently-playing-song).

Whilst that question was about C#, in the answer there is a [JavaScript specific reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd564018%28VS.85%29.aspx).  You may, for the purposes of Metro's sandboxing, need to consider the manifesting options to make this available to you.

Comment: Does this "desktop apps only" mean I can't use it within a metro application or I can't use it for WP7 apps?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but at a recent presentation I attended, Microsoft stated that your "existing code" could be called from Metro, you may just have to put appropriate entries in the manifests.  I would imagine on a Windows-8 machine you should be able to make use of this if you look at the interop documentation. WP7 I imagine is a different issue.