# How to listen to windows events in C#?

Tags: c#, com-interop, winapi, wmp

I'm developing an lyrics related application and I need to listen to Windows Media Player Events.
I watched windows events in "Accessible event watcher" and I found out that there's some events that WMP sends whenever it's state or current position changes.
I searched and found this article on MSDN [a How to set a Windows hook in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=318804) but I couldn't make it work.

How can I listen to that events from my C# application or any suggestions on using other methods to get current song and WMP playing status?\

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article describes how to get the events using the `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` which is the underlying root of the windows media player system. You will see that the various state change events can be picked up normally.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562388(v=vs.85).aspx

You should be able to get a running instance from the windows ROT (Running objects table)?

http://www.darinhiggins.com/the-running-instance-of-windows-media-player/

Edit:

This is another way...

http://www.darinhiggins.com/gaining-access-to-a-running-instance-of-windows-media-player-in-vb-net/

Comment: Thanks Visual Micro, I believe this will create a new instance of WMP control on the form, but I need to access the own WMP of the windows not creating a new one.

Comment: Is there any way to access the main WMP instance of the system from the ActiveX?

Comment: I've checked out that link you've sent. I was new to ROT, Its exactly what I want. but it doesn't work with Windows Media Player. I have a trouble with WMP's progId. I've tested the GetActiveObjects (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject) with some other applications like Word2010 and it worked with this progId 'Word.Application'. How can I get progId for Windows Media Player?

Comment: That sounds a bit of a pain. I've seen a few possibilities but have extended the answer above with something interesting. I hope :)

Comment: Thank you. I've checked it out a little. I think that's the solution:)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you? http://forums.msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/clr/thread/dbd43d7e-f3a6-4087-be06-df17e76b635d . There's also this post here [Getting windows media player currently playing song](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681576/getting-windows-media-player-currently-playing-song) that may answer your questions.

Comment: I checked out the articles you suggested, but they can be used when using the WMP control on windows forms, but I need to get current media and state of the song that user is playing in the own WMP of windows.