# Getting current windows media player instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, com, win32com, wmp

I am trying to integrate the current media name/artist in my python app and I can't seem to get it to work.

I did the same thing with iTunes with almost no issues whatsoever but for some reasons I can't manage to get the correct instance of windows media player

```
wmp = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("WMPlayer.OCX")
```

gets me a valid wmp instance but when I try to get the current media using

```
wmp.currentMedia
```

It returns nothing whatsoever and getting the volume like this:

```
wmp.settings.volume
```

returns a different volume than my actual opened windows media player volume.

Is there something I'm not aware of? I tried using WMPlayer.OCX.7 as well, but that doesn't work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what your code currently does is create a separate instance of the media player.

Comment: Only possible if you run python 2.x, as you need to implement a custom interface using `comtypes` Infos here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452001/need-a-way-to-retrieve-the-current-playing-song-from-zune-and-windows-media-play and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613750/heavily-confused-by-win32api-com-and-an-answer-from-so

Answer (score 1):

Windows Media Player supports several runnable instances.  Creating the OCX in the way you're doing creates *a separate instance* of the player, which, of course, doesn't have any media loaded.

The usual way to find the "master" instance would be to look in the Running Object Table, but Windows Media Player doesn't do that.  Instead, you need to use ["remote" mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This isn't terribly well documented, but there's a [VB.Net sample here](http://www.darinhiggins.com/gaining-access-to-a-running-instance-of-windows-media-player-in-vb-net/), translated from a [C# sample here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/dbd43d7e-f3a6-4087-be06-df17e76b635d/).  There are C++ samples in the Windows SDK, in the `\Multimedia\WMP_11\cpp\RemoteSkin` directory.

None of this, unfortunately, is in Python.  But hopefully the existing samples will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try and use something like `GetObject(None, "WMPlayer.OCX"))` insted of `EnsureDispatch`?  I think that `EnsureDispatch` makes a separate .exe instance typically.  Using `GetObject` should 'latch' onto the current instance and make it available as an object.

Comment: This is a very good tip, unfortunately this lead to an `Operation not available` error (-2147221021).