# Windows Spotify integration

Tags: c++, windows, integration, spotify

I'm trying to integrate the current playing song by Spotify in a program I am making I know Spotify itself doesn't have an API but windows shows the playing song when you pause the music with F7 or lower/upper your volume is there any way to get that song in c++?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting windows media player currently playing song](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681576/getting-windows-media-player-currently-playing-song)

Comment: This is a question for a search engine.

Comment: I only post when I cant find the method I want to use by searching

Comment: This question is exceedingly thin on specifics. If you're going to ask here, that's fine, but at least **show us what you've tried**, some kind of partial solution, so we can fill in the blanks.

Comment: There is no API available for that.