# Current playing item in Windows Media Player (wmplayer.exe ver. 12)

Tags: c#, .net, mp3, windows-media-player, wmplib

Been trying this for a while now.
All solutions I've seen on the net don't seem to work, specially the really simple way to do it.

`WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer c = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();

IWMPMedia i = (IWMPMedia)c.currentMedia;`

c.currentMedia is always null.

It seems that new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer(); is always creating a new instance of the Windows Media Player.
First I thought it was the fact that I was running visual studio as Administrator, but changing that did not help.

Seems I somehow have to connect to the running instance of wmplayer.exe but have unable to find a way to do that.

Btw. What I need is a full file url for the current playing song (or fullurl if streaming, but that's the least of my concerns now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question answered [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/0f784799-f50b-46da-857b-b08373bcceef).

> 1. A pretty straight way:
>
>    Get a WMP9 plugin here that will put your current song name on the
>      titlebar of the WMP window, and use
>      FindWindow P/Invoke to get the window
>      and get the song name. It shoud work,
>      though a little tricky.
>
>    Check [here](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-265768.html) for more details.
>
>    [Windows Media Player 9 Series Blogging Plug-in](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=61fab618-43cc-4c1c-b385-7cae06926298&DisplayLang=en)
> 2. A much more complex way:
>
>    Since your application and the WMP will be different processes, your
>      scenario requires some kind of
>      inter-process-communication (IPC). And
>      .NET offers Remoting for this purpose.
>
>    Below are some useful information:
>
>    [How to interact with Windows Media Player in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478/how-to-interact-with-windows-media-player-in-c)
>
>    [Windows Media Player Remoting in C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/clr/thread/dbd43d7e-f3a6-4087-be06-df17e76b635d)

from [SamAgain](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/samagain/?type=forum&referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/0f784799-f50b-46da-857b-b08373bcceef)

Comment: I think the first method is pretty ugly & hacky (to say the least). I recommend using the COM wrapper solution from (2), not too simple maybe but makes much more sense.