# How to Append/Queue Media File to the Current Media Player program in C#.net?

Tags: c#, media-player

I used:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"D:\Song1.mp3");
```

It played the MP3 file with my default Media Play (e.g Window Media Player);

I have another MP3 File (e.g D:\Song2.mp3) that i want to append/queue to the current Media Player. Anyone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [Windows Media Player SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd758070.aspx). Once setup you will be able queue/append media file programically.

Comment: I've just downloaded Windows Media Player SDK, but I don't know to use use it yet.

Would you please give me an example that could solve my problem above?

Comment: @HIA YongKuy, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478/how-to-interact-with-windows-media-player-in-c they show a few links that could help get you started.