# C# Get current song source url from Windows Media Player

Tags: c#, api, com, wmplib

i am trying to create a small application that notifies the user of the path of the current song being played on Windows Media Player.

So i have searched around and came across a good code:

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
// Get an interface to the first media item in the library. 
WMPLib.IWMPMedia3 firstMedia = (WMPLib.IWMPMedia3)player.mediaCollection.getAll().get_Item(0);

// Make the retrieved media item the current media item.
player.currentMedia = firstMedia;

// Display the name of the current media item.
currentMediaLabel.Text = ("Found first media item. Name = " + player.currentMedia.name);
```

But the problem is that this code actually fetches the first song on the list instead of getting the current song, i have tried changing the methods but no good :( and i wish you could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it already in `player.currentMedia`.

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();

// start the player
...

if(player.currentMedia != null)
{
    // Display the name of the current media item.
    currentMediaLabel.Text = ("Found first media item. Name = "
                              + player.currentMedia.name);
}
```

Comment: It ain't work, i get this error:
System.NullReferenceException

Comment: That means `player.currentMedia` is null which is the case if no song is playing yet. In your code you should verify that `player.currentMedia` is not null before accesing its properties.

Answer (score 0):

a few links for you.

Basicly

1. get the window title of windows media player
2. programaticly

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0f784799-f50b-46da-857b-b08373bcceef/getting-the-current-song-name-in-windows-media-player-c

http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-265768.html

[How to interact with Windows Media Player in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478/how-to-interact-with-windows-media-player-in-c-sharp)