# How can I tell if the state of the media player in windows 8 is playing/paused/stopped?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I need to integrate a piece of code into my WPF project that can tell if the windows 8 media player is in play or stop mode.

I have a button that plays/pauses using virtual keys, but I'd like the button to change according to the state of the media (display a triangle if the state is paused, and a "||" pause sign when its playing...). --- How then can I find out what the state is?

just to clarify - I'm talking about the media player that is started through metro and has a floating grey media control box in the upper right corner when it is running in the background.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478/how-to-interact-with-windows-media-player-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Xavjer Thanks but the link provided doesn't really answer my question  and also has broken links.